# Play a beep from a Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'd like to play a beep with the buzzer from a Docker image.

So far, I've been able to play a beep using the following command:

```
echo -e "\a" > /dev/console
```

This works correctly under Ubuntu 20.04.

I've tried to encapsulate this code into a Docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo 'for i in {1..5}' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo 'do' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo '  echo "B"' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo '  echo -e "\\a" > /dev/console' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo '  sleep 0.5' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo 'done' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo 'sleep infinity' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh
CMD /bootstrap.sh
```

To run the image, I've used the following command:

```
docker run -t -i --privileged -v /dev/console:/dev/console bell
```

This does not produce any sound. I've also tried to start a shell into the image but the commands only returns an empty string.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: Can't make the command `echo -e "\a" > /dev/console`  works on my Ubuntu 20.04. I have a "Permission denied" when redirecting to `/dev/console`. And if I only run `echo -e "\a"` I get a void output.

Comment: You need probably to enable buzzer: `sudo sed -i 's/blacklist pcspkr/#blacklist pcspkr/g' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf && modprobe pcspkr;`

Comment: I made it work switching to `/dev/tty0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, add:

```
echo -e "\a" > /dev/tty0
```

Then bind the interface to the docker instance:

```
docker run -t -i --privileged -v /dev/tty0:/dev/tty0 bell
```